# Python: KeyError whet trying to print the value of a pandas series element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to run a machine learning classifier. It works well. But when I am trying to  print the value of a test array , it says key error. Key error normally shows when the metadata is not present. But here you can see the y_test[index] exists.

```
data = pd.read_csv("fakenews.csv")
#print(data)
text = data.text
label = data.label
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text,label,test_size=0.30)

tfidf_vector = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.7)
tfidf_train = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(x_train)
tfidf_test = tfidf_vector.transform(x_test)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf_nav = GaussianNB()
clf_nav.fit(tfidf_train.todense(),y_train)
print(clf_nav.predict(tfidf_test[1].todense()))
print(y_test[0])
test_score = accuracy_score(clf_nav.predict(tfidf_test.todense()),y_test)
```

and the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-87eea68c37cc> in <module>()
      3 clf_nav.fit(tfidf_train.todense(),y_train)
      4 print(clf_nav.predict(tfidf_test[1].todense()))
----> 5 print(y_test[0])
      6 test_score = accuracy_score(clf_nav.predict(tfidf_test.todense()),y_test)
      7 print(test_score*100)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    621         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    622         try:
--> 623             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    624 
    625             if not is_scalar(result):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2558         try:
   2559             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2560                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2561         except KeyError as e1:
   2562             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Try checking `type(y_test)` or print it without the index. What does it show?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: have you tried list(y_test)[0] instead? *EDIT: Or y_test.tolist()[0] ?

Comment: Maybe you can try y_test.iloc[0]. This is the prefered way to go for positional indexing.

Comment: it works. @FlorianH

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get the first element, try to use y_test.iloc[0]. If you use y_test[0] pandas will try to retrieve an element with the index value of 0 which may not exist in your set since your test set is only a part of the complete dataset.